# Nativescript ssl pining issue

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have to enable ssl pining in my app. So, I had to use https://github.com/gethuman/nativescript-https plugin. 
I have follow the implementation steps correctly. But when I make the https request, iOS app crash in AFNetworking EXC_BAD_Access error

[image]

Android app gives this error

```
JS: nativescript-https > Disabled SSL pinning by default
JS: nativescript-https > enableSSLPinning error ReferenceError: okhttp3 is not defined
JS: Https.request error ReferenceError: okhttp3 is not defined
```

Certs folder
[image]

reference.d.ts

```
/// <reference path="./node_modules/tns-core-modules/tns-core-modules.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/android.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/ios.d.ts" />
```

imports

```
import { File, Folder, knownFolders, path } from 'file-system'
import * as Https from 'nativescript-https'
```

in the constructor

```
let dir = knownFolders.currentApp().getFolder('certs')
let certificate = dir.getFile('httpbin.org.cer').path
Https.enableSSLPinning({ host: 'httpbin.org', certificate: certificate});
```

method

```
clickLogin(){
        Https.request({
            url: 'https://httpbin.org/get',
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            },
        }).then(function(response) {
            console.log('Https.request response', response)
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.error('Https.request error', error)
        })
}
```

Please help me to identify whats is the issue here.

tns version 4.0.1
node v6.11.5

Comment: The iOS error seems to be related to a bug in the used POD - see here for details https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/6211#issuecomment-415419304

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android: Remove and re-add android platform. Clean build resolve the issue
iOS : Downgrade to Afnetworking 3.1.0 resolve the issue